# How to make a column in listview editable in K2 Five?

Tags: k2

In K2 5.3, we can make the whole row editable in listview. But I want to make one column editable and rest should be in readable mode. That editable column might be a drop down list or might be simple text. Is it possible to do this in K2 listview? Please suggest if there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "Read-Only"

Check this image:
[image]